# When an item is edited in one sharepoint list, what flow triggers do you use to edit the corresponding item in another sharepoint list?

Tags: flow, linked

I have two SharePoint lists, Travel Requests and Travel Calendar, that are currently linked together using Flow.

The first flow that I have set up, and is working appropriately, automatically starts an approval when an item is added to the Travel Request SharePoint List. When the travel request is approved, I used a "Create Item" action in the flow to create an item in the Travel Calendar SharePoint list, which again, is working very well.

However, if an item is edited in the Travel Request SharePoint list (for example, if the travel dates change), that change is not being reflected in the Travel Calendar list.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: You need to update the corresponding item in calendar list as well using your flow.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could have a separate flow that ran any time the main list was modified. It would be helpful to add a field to the calendar list to store the id of the travel request, and write that value as part of the original workflow. With that in place, when the travel request is modified, you could query the calendar for the item with the matching travel request id, and then update it.

Comment: Would that just be making a flow that is: 

When an item is modified in Travel Requests > get item in Travel Calendar > Update item in travel calendar?

Comment: Correct! provided you have some way of looking up the right item in travel calendar, it shouldn't be too difficult